# Understanding the notion of an "abstract set"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

This is likely a very minor question. I'm reading *Basic Complex Analysis* by Marsden and Hoffman, and they use the term "abstract set." I'm not fully sure what this means. I assume this means a set whose elements we haven't described explicitly, but rather which is defined by its properties. Is this the correct idea? If anyone has an example of such a set, I think it'd be easier to understand.

Comment: Without context, it might not be possible to say. Please type up an example (avoid using an image if possible)

Comment: There isn't a universally established notion of "abstract set", so it all boils down to what it means for a set to be "abstract" in the context of what the passage is talking about.

Comment: I have the book, can you specify which page the term was used?

Comment: @DanielP It's at the bottom of page 1, right below heading 1.1.

Comment: He just wants to emphasis we are understand the "real numbers" as a complete abstraction and not pertaining or identifiable by any practical of physical definitions.  It's just a set with.... elements .... so that the set follows certain rules.  The rules are the *only* thing we know about the sets and its elements.

Comment: If we said The reals include the numbers we use to count with and others, that isn't abstract.  The only thing we know about the elements in the set are that... they are elements in a set.  The set has certain rules about the elements but it's just a "game" based on nothing *except* rules for the sake of rules.

Comment: Another example.  Suppose I said I had a set $\{a,b,c\}$ with an binary operator so that $a+a = a; b+b=a; c+c=b; a+b=c; b+a=b; a+c=b; c+a=b; b+c=a;c+b=c$ and a student asked "huh, what is that *really*?" and I said something like "actually these represent the three states of something when combined in a certain way" that would not be abstract.  But if I said "They aren't anything.  They are just three abstractions I labelled $a,b,c$ and I made up rules that are completely made up about how they can be combined".  That would be abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "abstract set of real numbers", is just the "set of real numbers", rigorously defined, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach). It can be defined using the set notation, with some additional operations and properties. An abstract set in this context can be thought of as the collection $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,\ge)$, where $+$ and $\cdot$ are (the usual) operations and $\ge$ is an ordering.

The additional property of this collection is that it is [Dedekind-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers). This property uses the $\mathbb{R}$ and the $\ge$ elements of the collection. The reason the author didn't simply use the word "set", is likely because this property requires an additional symbol outside of the set, namely "$\ge$".